# TeamCity - how to access environment variable in gradle

Tags: gradle, teamcity

I have specified environment variable named DIR in my build agent. It is visible in my parameters/environment variables section of my Build Agent properties. I want to access this variable from gradle. I don't know how. I tried many things like:

```
if (project.hasProperty("teamcity")) {

    println teamcity
    println teamcity["teamcity.build.properties.file"]
    def properties = file(teamcity["teamcity.build.properties.file"])
    println properties.DIR
            println DIR
            println env.DIR
}
```

My teamcity file looks like:

```
{teamcity.buildType.id=Taxi5Mobile_BuildDev, build.vcs.number.Taxi5Mobile_Taxi5devVCS=a23e58c8ff92, teamcity.version=8.1.1 (build 29939), teamcity.buildConfName=Build-dev, teamcity.agent.dotnet.agent_url=http://localhost:9090/RPC2, teamcity.build.id=111, agent.ownPort=9090, agent.name=MacAgent, build.number=82, teamcity.runner.properties.file=/Users/surecase/Desktop/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp/teamcity.runner3909938768619827374.properties, teamcity.build.changedFiles.file=/Users/surecase/Desktop/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp/changedFiles8064633368222257261.txt, teamcity.agent.cpuBenchmark=552, teamcity.build.workingDir=/Users/surecase/Desktop/buildAgent/work/88410410f80bbc04/Mobile/Android, agent.home.dir=/Users/surecase/Desktop/buildAgent, teamcity.auth.userId=TeamCityBuildId=111, teamcity.build.checkoutDir=/Users/surecase/Desktop/buildAgent/work/88410410f80bbc04, teamcity.configuration.properties.file=/Users/surecase/Desktop/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp/teamcity.config8874044708331653991.properties, build.vcs.number=a23e58c8ff92, teamcity.tests.recentlyFailedTests.file=/Users/surecase/Desktop/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp/testsToRunFirst6286498944890258669.txt, teamcity.projectName=Taxi5Mobile, agent.work.dir=/Users/surecase/Desktop/buildAgent/work, teamcity.build.tempDir=/Users/surecase/Desktop/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp, build.vcs.number.1=a23e58c8ff92, teamcity.auth.password=8dYVHDftOmXenz9cJjnCyctBrF5NKq7G, java.io.tmpdir=/Users/surecase/Desktop/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp, teamcity.build.properties.file=/Users/surecase/Desktop/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp/teamcity.build174113942945941853.properties, teamcity.agent.dotnet.build_id=111}
```

There are some files which contains properties but I don't know how to access them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables can be read using the standard Java API:

```
def dir = System.getenv("DIR")
```

It might make sense to use a name that's a little less ambiguous than `DIR`.